# How to run two different classes, having multiple method one by one using xml suite in seleniumwebdriver

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have following suite xml for running in selenium webdriver( using core jave)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Default suite">

  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">

<classes>
<class name="org.paladion.provian.TestCases.InfraMonitoringAlert">
    <methods>
        <include name='createDeviceProductinRepo'></include>
        <include name='createAlertinAlertRepo'></include>
        <include name='createMonitoredDeviceinRepo'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeConfigChangeFirwallAlert'></include>
        <include name='editoneAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeLoginFailureFirwallAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeLoginSuccessfulFirwallAlert'></include>
        <include name='publishSingleAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypePasswordChangeOSAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeCriticalAlertsFirwallAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeUserAdditionDeletionFirewallAlert'></include>
        <include name='publishAllunpublishAlertsinLogMonitoring'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeCriticalAlertsIPSAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeUserAdditionDeletionOSAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeForceLogoutAlert'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeServerShutdownRestart'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeInterfaceCriticalErrorsFirewall'></include>
        <include name='suppressAllUnpublishAlerts'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeFirewallReboot'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeMiscellaneous'></include>
        <include name='createAlertForTypeLogStoppageAlert'></include>
    </methods> 
     </class>
     <class name="org.paladion.provian.TestCases.testUpload">
    <methods>
        <include name='assetsUpload'></include>
        <include name='usersUpload'></include>
        <include name='vareportUpload'></include>
        <include name='ptreportUpload'></include>
        <include name='appsecreportUpload'></include>
    </methods>
  </class>   
</classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->

</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

After ran this suite, its launching properly but first executing 2nd class( class name="org.paladion.provian.TestCases.testUpload" ) instead of 1st class. I want to execute first all the mention methods of 1st class ( class name="org.paladion.provian.TestCases.InfraMonitoringAlert" ) one by one then all the methods of 2nd class. Kindly suggest me how do i do this.

Comment: Did you add "priority" to your test methods?

Comment: I prioritize my methods and its working now.....thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what TestNG docs say:

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file to be run in an unpredictable order, set the `preserve-order` attribute to `false`

Normally your suite should work as you expect. I would suggest that you make sure these two classes are not in hierarchy of each other.

Comment: @BikramSarkar Glad I could help. Please, accept the answer in return then.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your testng.xml:-

```
<suite name="Default suite" group-by-instances="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

your test tag should be something like below,

```
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test" preserve-order=true>
```